# How to filter out nodes and only show ways and relations on Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to learn how to use Overpass Turbo, and as I was exploring, I thought it would be fun to map out my public transportation system to show the paths the busses cover. I only want to see the paths to show the extent the transportation system.

When I tried the following, It showed ways and relations as well as nodes covering all of the bus stops and train stations

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(  
relation["operator"="Toronto Transit Commission"]({{bbox}});
);
out geom;
```

Is there any way to filter out the nodes and only keep the paths (ways and relations)?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all nodes with the help of [MapCSS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/MapCSS).

Add the following MapCSS styling to the end of your query:

```
{{style:
node {
  opacity:0.0;
  fill-opacity:0.0;
}
}}
```